# How to stop reopening workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code.

```
Sub movedata()
    Dim i As Long

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wb2 As Workbook

    Dim L1 As Variant, L2 As Variant, L3 As Variant, L4 As Variant,l6 as variant
     Variant, L6 As Variant, L7 As Variant, L8 As Variant

    Dim sht1 As Worksheet

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set sht1 = wb.Sheets("PKG Avail Days")
    LastRow = sht1.Range("D:O").Find("*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    For i = 5 To LastRow

        L1 = sht1.Range("D" & i).Value
        L2 = sht1.Range("E" & i).Value
        L3 = sht1.Range("F" & i).Value
        L4 = sht1.Range("K" & i).Value
        L5 = sht1.Range("L" & i).Value
        L6 = sht1.Range("M" & i).Value
        L7 = sht1.Range("N" & i).Value
        L8 = sht1.Range("O" & i).Value

        Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("\\NMFPLPCLB130010\Users\stamarae\loglog.xlsx")

        wb2.Sheets(1).Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = L1
        wb2.Sheets(1).Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = L2
        wb2.Sheets(1).Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = L3
        wb2.Sheets(1).Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = L4
        wb2.Sheets(1).Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = L5
        wb2.Sheets(1).Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = L6
        wb2.Sheets(1).Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = L7
        wb2.Sheets(1).Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = L8

    Next i

End Sub
```

I get

> Run-time Error '1004' - Method 'Open' of object 'Workbooks' failed.

and a prompting message

> "xxxx" is already open. reopening will cause
>   any changes you made to be discarded. do you want to reopen
>   "xxx.xlsx?"

Comment: Somehow the workbook may be closed  but not completely, if you look in task manager, you may see that the workbook is still open

Comment: I checked task manager but its still happening

Comment: Maybe a stupid question but: what is the name of the workbook containing this macro?

Comment: It’s called update rtm.xlsm

Comment: Please provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of code that has this problem.  Also, does the problem occur when using Workbooks.Open to open *any* workbook, or only for loglog.xlsx?

Comment: I have changed the workbook name severally but it still happening. I have even opened a new workbook yet it’s still happening. It’s debugging that the workbooos.open failed. Could it be that it an application problem?

Answer (score 2):

This is what happens when you put

`Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("\\NMFPLPCLB130010\Users\stamarae\loglog.xlsx")`

within `For i = 5 To LastRow` Loop. Macro tries to open the same file for each row, without closing previous instance.

Comment: Thanks guys. i really i appreciate this. its working fine and faster now.

Comment: However, column M in the "pkg avail days" contains fomular and the empty cells are pasting zero on the destination sheet. i tried this but its giving error messages                                                                              
        If .Range("K:O").Rows("5:" & LastRow) = "" Then
                                                                                                        
          Else
        sht2.Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value
        End If
        End With
    
    
End Sub

Comment: Try replacing all occurences of `.Value` in DisplayName's code with `.Formula`. Keep in mind that this problem was also in your original code.

Comment: thanks Ryszard, i am aware of that. however i tried  .Formula   but it didn't work. i  am trying to copy only values and not the formula. as column M contains formula, its pasting or returns zero on the destination sheet. i dont want that. once there's no value, it should simply return or paste nothing.

Comment: If it's indeed the values that need to be pasted, then zero appearing on target worksheet is the sign that result of formula is 0 and 0 by no means can be called "no value". In such case you can handle the reason: formula should be changed, so that it returns "" if the result is 0, then a null string will fill the cell, this will in almost all aspects act as an empty cell. You also may play with a macro and create a loop to replace zeros in output with `Empty`, then you will have a truly empty cell, but all loops of this kind are preferably done on arrays, not range, due to performance.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I still don’t know what to do. Can you help me with a code that could work or a link to a good example. Thanks again Jedraszyk

Comment: Do you have a possibility to alter formula in workbook with macros? If the formula is something like: "=D2-D4", then change it to "=IF(D2-D4<>0,D2-D4,""). I used comma as a separator in this formula, but for some regional settings default is semicolon.

Comment: For macro solution you can do something like `sht2.Columns("M").Replace what:=0, replacement:=Empty, LookAt:=xlWhole`

Comment: the code didn't work for some reason that would have been perfect. however, here is the formular:  (D5-E5)*1440. how do i use "if" syntax on this fomula to make it retun empty when column D5 and E5 is empty

Comment: No idea why it didn't worked as I don't see it within the code. Here are 2 formulas for this date difference in minutes, 1st - if the difference is 0 (doesn't check if cells are empty or not): =IF(D5-E5*1440<>0,D5-E5*1440<>0,"")  2nd - if any cell with date is empty (doesn't check if they are the same and result is 0): =IF(OR(D5="",E5=""),"",D5-E5*1440)

Comment: the formulas isn't working. However, thank you for all your help, if you happen to come across something that could work  i will be glad to try it.

Comment: =IF((E10-D10)*1440,(E10-D10)*1440,"").   This formula was able to do it. Thanks for all your help.  One last thing please, how do I copy the last cell oF a column (thats sht2 column B) and  paste on the same column till the last non empty row on column D of same sheet?

Answer (score 1):

@Ryszard Jędraszyk told you the why of your issue

here's how you can simplify and speed up your code with no loops:

```
Sub movedata()
    Dim LastRow As Long            
    Dim sht2 As Worksheet

    Set sht2 = Workbooks.Open("\\NMFPLPCLB130010\Users\stamarae\loglog.xlsx").Sheets(1) ' set "destination" sheet as sheet 1 of the opened workbook 

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PKG Avail Days") ' reference "source" sheet
        LastRow = .Range("D:O").Find("*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

        With .Range("D:F").Rows("5:" & LastRow) ' reference referenced sheet columns D to F cells from row 5 down to 'LastRow'
            sht2.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value ' paste referenced range values to "destination" sheet form column D first empty cell after last not empty one
        End With

        With .Range("K:O").Rows("5:" & LastRow) 
            sht2.Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me. The good thing is that no error condition was invoked:

```
MainCode:
    'sName = workbook.xlsm
    'sPathName = "c:\directory\structure\workbook.xlsm"
    'NEXTITEM is an emum with a value of 1

    If Not ItemCount(sName) Then
        Workbooks.Open (sPathName)
    end if

    '....

Function ItemCount(ByVal s As String) As Boolean

    Dim i As Integer

    ItemCount = False
    For i = NEXTITEM To Application.Workbooks.Count
        If Application.Workbooks.Item(i).Name = s Then
            ItemCount = True
        End If
    Next i

End Function
```